# How to improve ANN results by reducing error through hidden layer size, through MSE, or by using while loop?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

This is my source code and I want to reduce the possible errors. When running this code there is a lot of difference between trained output to target. I have tried different ways but didn't work so please help me reducing it.

```
a=[31 9333 2000;31 9500 1500;31 9700 2300;31 9700 2320;31 9120 2230;31 9830 2420;31 9300 2900;31 9400 2500]'
g=[35000;23000;3443;2343;1244;9483;4638;4739]'
h=[31 9333 2000]'


inputs =(a);
targets =[g];

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 1;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);

% Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};


% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand';  % Divide data randomly
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% For help on training function 'trainlm' type: help trainlm
% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt
% Choose a Performance Function
% For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance
net.performFcn = 'mse'; % Mean squared error

% Choose Plot Functions
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
  'plotregression','plotconfusion' 'plotfit','plotroc'};
% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
plottrainstate(tr)

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs)
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs)
fprintf('errors = %4.3f\t',errors);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs);

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs);
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs);
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs);

% View the Network
view(net);
sc=sim(net,h)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be more specific.

What is the performance like on your training set and on your test set?

Have you tried doing any regularization?